# Importing a word (styles) that does not exist in the imported file? (React Native / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a noob learning React Native and I see examples (such as the below) where "**styles**" is imported but I do not see that word "styles" anywhere in the imported file or as the file name. I was expecting the import term to be "stylesheet" since that what is what the imported file does have.  Is it some kind of magic keyword and if so where do I learn of those?  I read the React Native documentation on the stylesheet [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet) but didn't see any mention of styles being a special term; in fact they appear to name a variable "styles" and assign it to the return of function stylesheet.create which is what I would expect.  Been trying to google these terms but clearly I am searching for the wrong things.

For example in Sec 4.2 of this guide:  https://www.reactnative.guide/5-project-structure-and-start-building-some-app/5.2-basic-components-and-platform-specific-code.html

In the first part of that page there is a text UI element at `app/components/TextArea/TextArea.component.js` which contains an import of "styles" on line 4:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './TextArea.component.style';

class TextArea extends Component {
  state = {
    text : ''
  }
  render() {
    const {...extraProps} = this.props;
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...extraProps}
        style={[styles.textArea, extraProps.style]}
        multiline = {true}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TextArea;
```

The imported file is `app/components/TextArea/TextArea.component.style.js` and contains no mention of the word "styles". Only stylesheet is mentioned which is what I guess I would've thought the import name would be. Or the filename which has "style" singular, not plural.  I thought they'd need to assign a variable name to the output of stylesheet.create to export it with a name.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  textArea: {
    width: 200,
    height:100,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of default exports, when you `export default` something, you can import from another file without using a specific name. You can only have one default export per file.

If instead you exported something without using the `default` keyword, you’d have to import it by putting the variable name inside curly braces `import { x } from ‘path/to/file`. You can have as many named exports as you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can import it and use it as by any name you want, since the function has been exported without an specific name, as

```
export default function(){ }
```

```
import myStyle from './TextArea.component.style';
```

Or

```
import Test from './TextArea.component.style';
```

The above statement simply says that get default function as Test from the './TextArea.component.style' file, if present

you can only export default a single function or class in one file otherwise it will throw an error